# How can I download file loaded by XMLHTTPRequest via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, xmlhttprequest

I want to download file, right now I am using 
        window.location.href
but it use second call of my servlet to generate file and file generates about 1 minute, how can I download it from XMLHTTPRequest.
It must work only with Internet Explorer 7+
How can I get file without window.location.href

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : fileUrl,
    success : function(response){
        var resp = response.responseText;
        if (resp.indexOf('error')>-1){
            //some logic
        }else{
            window.location.href = fileUrl;
        }

    }
    }
});
```

Comment: Header of my file is  `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=[generatedName].csv`, and content type is `application/x-download;charset=windows-1251`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to download a file with XMLHTTPRequest.
Because you want support for IE7+, I recommend to use an IFrame and set the src on the IFrame. Dont forget that your header from the server must contain `Content-Disposition: attachment;`